# C++ Nvidia PhysX cannot convert PxFoundation to shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, physx

Im trying to create a PxFoundation and save it in my member variable "foundation" which is a std::shared_ptr. However upon creating the object I get this:

```
C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'physx::PxFoundation *' to 'std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>'
```

How can I put the raw pointer from the PxCreateFoundation function into a shared_ptr? as I'm not calling the ctor of any PhysX class I cannot use std::make_shared, so using the normal std::shared_ptr<>() constructor seems my only option?

Code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <PxPhysics.h>
#include "PhysXErrorCallback.hpp"
#include "PhysXDefaultAllocator.hpp"
#include <foundation/PxFoundationVersion.h>

class PhysicsEngine
{
public:


    PhysicsEngine();

    std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation> foundation;

    static PhysXErrorCallback gDefaultErrorCallback;
    static PhysXDefaultAllocator gDefaultAllocatorCallback;
};

PhysicsEngine::PhysicsEngine()
{
    foundation =  std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>(PxCreateFoundation(PX_FOUNDATION_VERSION, gDefaultAllocatorCallback, gDefaultErrorCallback));
}
```

**EDIT:**
After chaning the

```
foundation = std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>(...)
```

to

```
foundation.reset(...)
```

it now gives me these errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1519): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'physx::PxFoundation *' to 'std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1519): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>physicsengine.cpp(25): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>::reset<physx::PxFoundation>(_Ux *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ux=physx::PxFoundation
1>        ]
1>physicsengine.cpp(25): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>::reset<physx::PxFoundation>(_Ux *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ux=physx::PxFoundation
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1519): error C2228: left of '.swap' must have class/struct/union
```

**EDIT2:**

Heres the PxCreateFoundation declaration and definition:

```
PX_C_EXPORT PX_FOUNDATION_API physx::PxFoundation* PX_CALL_CONV
PxCreateFoundation(physx::PxU32 version, physx::PxAllocatorCallback& allocator, physx::PxErrorCallback& errorCallback);

physx::PxFoundation* PxCreateFoundation(physx::PxU32 version, physx::PxAllocatorCallback& allocator,
                                    physx::PxErrorCallback& errorCallback)
{
    return physx::shdfnd::Foundation::createInstance(version, errorCallback, allocator);
}
```

PxFoundation class:

```
/**
\brief Foundation SDK singleton class.

You need to have an instance of this class to instance the higher level SDKs.
*/
class PX_FOUNDATION_API PxFoundation
{
  public:
    virtual void release() = 0;

  protected:
    virtual ~PxFoundation()
    {
    }
};
```

createInstance definition:

```
Foundation* Foundation::createInstance(PxU32 version, PxErrorCallback& errc, PxAllocatorCallback& alloc)
{
//...
    mInstance = reinterpret_cast<Foundation*>(alloc.allocate(sizeof(Foundation), "Foundation", __FILE__, __LINE__));

    if(mInstance)
    {
        PX_PLACEMENT_NEW(mInstance, Foundation)(errc, alloc);
        return mInstance;
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: How is `PxCreateFoundation` declared? Please provide minimal compilable code

Comment: Im unsure I'f im allowed to simply post the content of the PhysX 3.4 SDK here. What should I do?

Comment: Post relevant context: function declaration, stripped down class definition...

Comment: Alright, I posted all relevant PxFoundation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found the error:
Most destructors in PhysX SDK are not public. Therefore trying to create a smart pointer with one of these classes results in an error.
Only other option beside using a raw pointer would be to create a custom deleter:

```
auto foundation = std::shared_ptr<physx::PxFoundation>(PxCreateFoundation(PX_FOUNDATION_VERSION, gDefaultAllocatorCallback, gDefaultErrorCallback), [=](physx::PxFoundation* f)
{
    f->release();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `foundation =` line isn't actually calling a constructor.  It's trying to cast the raw pointer to a `shared_ptr` using the syntax called a "functional cast" or "function-style cast" (#2 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)), and then assign the result to the `foundation` variable (which has already been default-constructed).  That won't work because `shared_ptr` has no cast from a raw pointer (to prevent it from accidentally taking ownership of things it shouldn't).

The best way to fix the problem is to use your constructor's initializer list to actually initialize `foundation` with the pointer:

```
PhysicsEngine::PhysicsEngine() :
foundation(PxCreateFoundation(PX_FOUNDATION_VERSION, gDefaultAllocatorCallback, gDefaultErrorCallback))
{
  // empty
}
```

This passes the pointer to `foundation`'s constructor, as opposed to letting `foundation` be default-constructed and then assigning to it afterward in the constructor body.  But if you really need to do it by assignment for some reason, you can use the [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) function to tell `foundation` to take ownership of the pointer:

```
PhysicsEngine::PhysicsEngine()
{
    foundation.reset(PxCreateFoundation(PX_FOUNDATION_VERSION, gDefaultAllocatorCallback, gDefaultErrorCallback));
}
```

Comment: Ah good to know! I decided to take the latter approach in case I don't want to init my physics on construction. However, it gives me the errors I edited into my question.

Comment: "_line isn't actually calling a constructor_" -1; a cast is a way to "call the ctor" "_(user defined type T) has no cast from (type U)_" There is no such thing as a UDT having a cast from some other type

Comment: "_This passes the pointer to foundation's constructor_" Please provide an example (compilable code) where an argument is acceptable in a ctor init list but not in a functional cast of the same type as the member being cted